# Properly indexing large Time Series dataset for complex query

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a large table of timeseries data. ~ 800 million rows. I need to properly index this large dataset. My UI has dropdown menus inputs as query selectors, allowing users to update the dataset/visualization.There are 7 potential user inputs that would prompt a query on the table

Generally the query order stays consistent. Stage>Week>Team>Opponent>Map>Round>Stat. Should I be creating a single multi-column index on this sequence? Or should i be applying multiple multi-column indexes? Or a third option of indexing each of the column that are user inputs individually. Which is the most efficient approach?

```
def timeseries (map,stage,week,stat,team,opponent,round):
    teams=[team,opponent]
    df=df[df.match_id == id_dict[stage][week][team][opponent]]
    df=df[df.mapname == map] 
    df=df[df.stat_type == stat]
    df=df[df.team.isin(teams)]
    df=df[df.map_round == round]

    --> df to visualization.
```

The first filter of match_id is a bit of a work around, as the user essentially selects a match id indirectly based on their other input selectors. (id_dict returns a single match id of a game)

Answer (score 0):

This article may be useful depending on the version of PostGRES you are running [PostGRES Indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) to summarize:

The database will combine as many single row indexes for optimization, but it will still have to cross reference full rows. If you know that some combinations of rows will be more popular then others, I'd make combined indexes on those for better performance. If you are not inserting into the table, having many indexes should not hurt.